# Overload is the only way to add different parameter to the same function?

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 functions that does the same exact operation; since the underlying API has an overloaded fuction that accept either a string or an int.

Since I am using this function, I need to call the function either with a string or with an int. Is overloading the only way to do so? I replicate the code, beside the signature of the function; and it seems a waste of code.

```
public void taketwo(int value1, int value2)
{
    // Other operations happen here
    baseAPI.getvalues(value1, value2);
}

public void taketwo(string val1_str, string val2_str)
{
    // Other operations happen here
    baseAPI.getvalues(val1_str, val2_str);
}
```

I recall something about generic function; but I am not sure if that would apply in this case; I never used them in the past, and before dive in, I thought that it was worth to ask around first.

Comment: `getvalues` itsself looks like it is overloaded if it is taking both strings adn ints

Comment: Correct; this is a simplified scenario. taketwo function is doing various operation; then it call getvalues passing either an int or a string. I am trying to consolidate everything in a single function, so I can call getvalues once, with the appropriate parameters.

Comment: As an aside, it's easier to read questions if you use idiomatic code, following the naming conventions of the platform you're using. Don't distract readers by using unconventional names.

Comment: It would appear that the secret to getting the community to offer up *bad code* is to ask it under a semi-hypothetical pretense.

Comment: @JonSkeet: not sure what do you mean by "idiomatic code following naming conventions"; I specified that it is C#, and kept it as generic as possible.

Comment: @newbiez: But you didn't follow the naming conventions of C# and .NET - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229045(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *could* use dynamic typing here:

```
// I don't recommend you do this - see later
public void TakeTwo(dynamic value1, dynamic value2)
{
    baseAPI.GetValues(value1, value2);
}
```

The overload resolution for the call to `GetValues` will then be performed at execution time.

However:

- There's no compile-time checking that your call to `TakeTwo` will be valid
- It is less efficient (which may or may not be significant; the first point is more important in most cases)

You talk about replicating code, but in the example you've shown *all* the code is the method call. If there's other code in the method which is genuinely common, I'd recommend extracting that common code out and calling it in both overloads:

```
public void TakeTwo(int value1, int value2)
{
    CommonCode();
    baseAPI.GetValues(value1, value2);
}

public void TakeTwo(string value1, string value2)
{
    CommonCode();
    baseAPI.GetValues(value1, value2);
}

private void CommonCode()
{
    // Things you want to do in both methods
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the best solution for my case. I did think about replicating code in a common function; but performance wise, it was not an option. I can live with the risk that TakeTwo won't be validate, since I am 99.9% of the correctness of what I pass in that specific case (not being cocky; the return type of a function that generate these 2 parameters is made so it will either return correct values; or it won't call TakeTwo at all). Thanks!

Comment: @newbiez: If the code is so performance sensitive that the overhead of extracting a method is prohibitive, chances are the overhead of using `dynamic` is going to be far worse...

Comment: @newbiez: Did you actually profile your code to see that extracting the common code into a method actually has any real performance impact? I highly doubt that this is the case.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth:I did profile the path that is calling the function; which gave me an idea of how much could impact. few ms may affect the outcome of my results; which is why I am trying to be as neat as possible.

Comment: @JonSkeet: so the usage of dynamic is going to add a noticeable overhead? In that case I have to avoid that solution. I guess that I have to try with the solution of common code in a different function and see how much time I loose. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @newbiez: As Jon said, the performance of the dynamic overload resolution is worse than a simple method call. Also, please keep in mind that your method could even be inlined by the compiler, effectively resulting in no overhead at all.

Comment: @newbiez: In general, you need to profile the specific solutions and compare the results. Your approach is flawed, because you are just guessing. In your case, you are guessing, that a method call costs you a few milliseconds. And that is not true. So, profile, then decide.

Comment: @newbiez: The overhead of a making a method call rather than inlining would be more likely to be in the sub-nanosecond range than milliseconds. I agree with everything Daniel has said.

Answer (score 3):

Do int and string parameters represent different concepts? If not, then you could code the implementation only once by calling 'string overload' from the 'int overload'

```
public void taketwo(int value1, int value2)
{
    taketwo(value1.ToString(), value2.ToString())
}

public void taketwo(string val1_str, string val2_str)
{
    // Other operations happen here
    baseAPI.getvalues(val1_str, val2_str);
}
```

This makes sense assuming there is more than just single API call in the methods.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version of code to handle above scenario. In my point of view it make sense to pass generic class instead of passing multiple parameter in function for flexibility.

> What if the api version got changed and need to handle third type like
>   decimal.

Below is the sample code which i though make it more flexible.

```
    public class MyValues<T>
    {
        public T value1 { get; set; }
        public T value2 { get; set; }
    }

    public void TakeTwo<T>(MyValues<T> myvalue)
    {
        baseAPI.getvalues(myvalue.value1, myvalue.value2);
    }
```

To call TakeTwo for typeof(string) we can use something like below.

```
    TakeTwo<string>(new MyValues<string>() { value1 = "string 1", value2 = "string 2" });
```

To call TakeTwo for typeof(string) we can use something like below.

```
    TakeTwo<int>(new MyValues<int>() { value1 = 123, value2 = 345 });
```

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You could put the duplicate code - that you marked with `// Other operations happen here` - into its own method, if applicable. Obviously, this only would work, if this duplicate code doesn't make use of the passed in parameters.

---

Generic methods can't be used here, because generics are a compile time feature, not a runtime feature.
What you could do would be to use `dynamic`. In that case, the overload resolution would happen at runtime. But it would have the disadvantage that you could also pass a `double` or `Uri` object and only at runtime you would get an exception, because no such overload exists for `baseAPI.getvalues`.

Code:

```
public void taketwo(dynamic value1, dynamic value2)
{
    // Other operations happen here
    baseAPI.getvalues(value1, value2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your `baseAPI` design you could use generics:

```
public void taketwo<T>(T val1, T val2)
{
    // Other operations happen here
    baseAPI.getvalues<T>(val1, val2);
}
```

but that would require making your `baseAPI.getvalues` generic in the first place.

Comment: You could check the type of T and cast the values before call to baseAPI in a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to recieve an object (upcast), which means he will be able to send a string or int, and then with a simple if else you can send it to the correct function based on the value of that object.

```
public void taketwo(Object value1, Object value2) { 

// Other operations happen here 

If (check if value1 is a number) {
  baseAPI.getvalues(value1, value2); 
} else {
  baseAPI.getvalues(val1_str, val2_str);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, technically you can combine all this parameters into one method and set them having default parameter `null`.

```
public void taketwo(int? value1 = null, int? value2 = null, 
                    string val1_str = null, string val2_str = null)
{
    if (value1 != null)
       baseAPI.getvalues(value1.Value, value2.Value);
    else if (val1_str != null)
       baseAPI.getvalues(val1_str, val2_str);
}
```

So you can call it as `taketwo(1, 2)` as well as `taketwo(val1_str:"str1", val2_str:"str2")` since all parameters has default values.

Will it be more convinient or not - it's up to you. Personally I'd prefer method overloading rather than combining all possible parameters into one method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I can pass parameters as optional, and then deal with it in the function. What would be the overload of this , versus having 2 overloaded function that share 90% of the code?

Comment: This seems like a pretty poor design.

Comment: @newbiez Personally I'd prefer method overloading rather then combining all possible parameters into one method.

Comment: @newbiez You may be able to refactor the duplicated code into a third method and call it from each overloaded method, leaving only the code that's applicable to each overload.  That said, There's no way I'd ever pass this code if I were the one reviewing it; it's *extremely* ill-conceived, but from a completely academic standpoint, it *does* provide an alternative to overloading.

Comment: That one **would NOT even compile** if you try to pass strings as args. You need to use int as the first argument anyway.

Comment: @bashis surely it can be compiled. probably you've missed the fact of  parameters names used in the case of call using strings parameters only.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev eventually i did. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: I always like to prioritize procedural abstraction over the ease of writing the methods. Meaning creating two different methods if `Method(myInt, true)` does not make sense semantically. This example does not give any abstraction and forces me to think about how the method works upon every call.